# Preventing default click event in qtip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I've created a link with a [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/) tooltip using the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="mylink">Show Tooltip</a>

$('.mylink').qtip({
  show: {event: 'click'}
});
```

When the link is clicked, the tooltip opens as expected, but the browser also navigates to `/#`, which causes the screen to scroll to the top. How can I prevent the original click event, without interfering with qtip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=1007&pid=4431#pid4431). Just bind to the click event of the link and use `preventDefault`.

```
$('.mylink').qtip({
  show: {event: 'click'}
}).bind('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); return false; });
```